# Retrieving data from a table based on values in a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have an hashmap with a key and value (Array of integers) `HashMap<key, array>` and I would like to retrieve data from a sql table with a column that matches the values in array stored in a hashmap

I can do this in two ways one getting all the data from table and iterating through hashmap and other being iterating through hashmap and applying the where clause in each iteration which makes n calls to database.

**Is there an efficient way to do this other than the above ?**

Comment: I presume either of them is inefficient , your SQL query should retrieve in one database call. If the result is too large to handle by your java client, handle it in batches.

Comment: It obviously depends on how large the table is, and how many entries are there in the hash map. Think about it: imagine, that there are ten entries in the hash map, and a hundred million rows in the table. Now, suppose, there ten thousand entries in the hash map, and a table with six rows. Do you see yet why you are not getting any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to set up a query having an `IN` condition in the `WHERE` clause.  This snippet should give you the general idea:

```
    values = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    String query =
        "SELECT film_id, title\n"
        + "FROM film\n"
        + "WHERE film_Id IN (";
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            query += ",";
        }
        query += "?";
    }
    query += ")";

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("db-url", "user", "pwd");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
            stmt.setInt(i+1, values[i]);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
            // process results
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You have to be careful with dynamic "in" statements when using Oracle since it has limit of 1000.